# Twitter - Query for tweets within a radius of a particular GeoLocation

Tags: java, twitter, geolocation, jersey, twitter4j

I am trying to form a query to the Twitter REST API. Is there a way to pass gps coordinates into the query and return tweets that are in a particular radius of that location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code below. Before trying it, you have to put some values into `keyword`, `latitude`, `longitude`, and `radius`. `keyword` is what you search about and I think you can understand what other values mean.

```
try {
        Query query = new Query(keyword); //

        GeoLocation location = new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude);
        String unit = Query.KILOMETERS; // or Query.MILES;
        query.setGeoCode(location, radius, unit);

        QueryResult result; 

        do {
            result = twitter.search(query);
            List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();

            for (Status tweet : tweets) {
                System.out.println("@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + tweet.getText());
            }

        } while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);

    } catch (TwitterException te) {
        System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [GET search/tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) endpoint you can specify geocode and radius to get a set of Tweets from within that region. The parameter value is as follows: latitude, longitude, radius.

Ex: 37.781157,-122.398720,1mi

Comment: Is there anyway of doing this using the Twitter4J Query?

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Seohyun Choi answer , this is complete java code with authentication.
Before compiling this code please add the **twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar** in path.

```
import java.util.List;
import twitter4j.GeoLocation;
import twitter4j.Query;
import twitter4j.QueryResult;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public class TweetsInParticularLocation {
    private static final String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "****";
    private static final String TWITTER_SECRET_KEY = "*****";
    private static final String TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN = "****";
    private static final String TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "***";
public static void main(String arg[])
{
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
        .setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY)
        .setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_SECRET_KEY)
        .setOAuthAccessToken(TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN)
        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

    try {
        Query query = new Query("India"); //

        GeoLocation location = new GeoLocation(20.593684, 78.962880); //latitude, longitude
        String unit = Query.KILOMETERS; // or Query.MILES;
        query.setGeoCode(location, 1, unit); //location, radius, unit

        QueryResult result; 

        do {
            result = twitter.search(query);
            List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();

            for (Status tweet : tweets) {
                System.out.println("@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + tweet.getText());
            }

        } while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);

    } catch (TwitterException te) {
        System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }

}}
```

Comment: Mr @mentya, I have the problem related to this thread, mind you visit to here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70921122/how-to-import-twitter-data-directly-into-database-from-crawling-by-geocode-with thanks before