# How to Import Twitter Data Directly Into Database from Crawling by GeoCode (with Radius)?

Tags: java, database, import, twitter4j, geocode

I am referring this thread :

[Twitter - Query for tweets within a radius of a particular GeoLocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751423/twitter-query-for-tweets-within-a-radius-of-a-particular-geolocation)

But my problem is I want to directly import it into database MySQL, instead of System.out.println.
How to do that?

I have this code in this far :

```
stmt = conne.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tweet(ID,date,name,text) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

stmt.setInt(1, (int) status.getId());

stmt.setString(2, getTimeStamp());

stmt.setString(3, status.getUser().getScreenName());

Query query = new Query("india");
GeoLocation location = new GeoLocation(20.593684, 78.962880);
String unit = Query.KILOMETERS;
    query.setGeoCode(location, 2, unit);
    QueryResult result;
    result = twitter.search(query);
    List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
    for (Status tweet : tweets){
stmt.setString(4, status.getText());
                            }
```

Then, I see the output error like this :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot use this builder any longer, build() has already been called
```

I figured out that I have two *build()*, that is one for TwitterStream and one for TwitterFactory :

```
TwitterStream twitterStream5 = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb5.build()).getInstance();
TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb5.build());
Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
```

But still, I do not know how to correct it.
Thank you for any comment !

Comment: By the way, I ever asked about importing from crawling Twitter data but with no GeoCode:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70844564/how-to-import-data-with-getgeolocation-twitter4j-to-mysql-using-java-netbeans then this thread is using GeoCode

Answer (score 0):

> I figured out that I have two build(), that is one for TwitterStream and one for TwitterFactory :

The problem is more about builder itself: you cannot reuse it after `build()` was called. You should have two separate builders.